# Either I don't know how to into Twitter, or the Twitter links in revision histories are broken

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, revisions-list, twitter

Consider the revision history of [How to delete every second line from a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/219859/), chosen more or less arbitrarily: https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/219859/revisions. There's a history event indicating that the post was tweeted on 3 Aug 2015 at 20:55 UTC, with the following link: http://twitter.com/#!/StackUnix/status/628308124953378816

When I click on that link, this is what I see:

[image]

This is the Twitter homepage. When I grab a permalink to a tweet directly from [the StackUnix account](https://twitter.com/StackUnix/), it's structured just like the link that's in the revision history, except minus the `#!/` part.

In case it matters, I am not logged into Twitter. I observe this behavior on Chrome 45 with AdBlock, Chrome 45 in incognito (no extensions), and IE 11, all on Windows 8.1. In Chrome, I just get a 200 OK for https://twitter.com/ (which makes sense, since everything after the `#` is being interpreted as part of the hash), but the page doesn't redirect me anywhere after that.

Am I just bad at Twitter, or are these links actually broken?

Comment: Clicking the `Tweeted twitter.com/#!/StackUnix/status/628308124953378816` redirects me to `https://twitter.com/StackUnix/status/628308124953378816`... so it works...

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ It doesn't redirect me.

Comment: but I do see the homepage for a second before I'm redirected - maybe you've got something blocking redirects??

Comment: It doesn't work for me in incognito but it works without incognito (and I'm logged into Twitter).

Comment: @hichris123 that is weird - I'm not logged in and it works in both incognito and normal...

Comment: No repro here, it is probably something on your end.

Comment: There is a 307 Internal Redirect header responsible for the redirect, what do you see in Chrome network tab?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hm, weird. I did get a 307 Internal Redirect, but only on one out of 20ish refreshes. (And it still didn't redirect that time.)

Comment: Weird indeed, didn't find anything that can possibly bork that redirection. Wonder if others suffer this issue..

Comment: For the record, Twitter seems to be redirecting these links *for logged in users*, but not for anons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed **for new Twitter links only** (we're not going to go into the database and retroactively fix existing links) as of build 2955 for SE.com, build 3738 on MSE/MSO, and build 2861 on other sites.